# Set value using php echo in select option tag

Tags: php, html

How do I get this to work?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="data[day]">Day:</label>
    <?php $day_of_week = array('','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday') ?>
    <select class="form-control">

        <?php foreach($day_of_week as $day):?>
        <option value="<?php echo $day; ?>"><?php echo $day; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </select>
</div>
```

I wanted the user to select day of the week using the combobox and it should return the value of the option tag into database.I am wondering why this method does not return any value in database. Any correction would be appreciated. This div tag is in form tag where it will return the form to the database.

Comment: "…does not return any value in sql…" - Uhm, which SQL now?

Comment: this div is in form tag. this is just part of the form just to make it simple

Comment: Then you simplified it too much. Code does exactly as instructured. But whatever you actually wanted to accomplish is left unspecified in your question.

Comment: You should put also your code with `<form>` tag and the `php` code file used in `form action`

Comment: Look at the result with `View Source` in the browser. Also check the Elements panel of Developer Tools to make sure everything is nested properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<select>` tag doesn't have a name, so the value won't be submitted to the server. It also doesn't have an `id`, so the label won't be linked with it.

```
<select id="data[day]" name="day" class="form-control">
```

When the form is submitted, the value will be in `$_POST['day']`.

Comment: This is the real reason why it didn't submit. I didn't notice because of the label tag attribute.